# Multiple Input/Output streams in Java?

Tags: java, networking

I ran into a problem while using input/output streams in Java. My thought was to have a `DataInputStream` to handle receiving text and a `PrintStream` to pass messages to the server from the server and object(output/input)streams to handle passing piece movements and current board image.

My problem is that the code hangs while it is trying to create the `ObjectInputStream` in the code below. Is this because I am trying to have multiple input and output streams? If so is there any possible fix I could use?

```
       Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1716);
       input = new DataInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
       printer = new PrintStream(sock.getOutputStream());

       System.out.println("Test 1");
       zelda = new ObjectInputStream(sock.getInputStream());
       System.out.println("Test 2");
       link = new ObjectOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
       System.out.println("Test 3");
```

I have a lot of Legend of Zelda references in my server source code and the code is rather large. The previous source code is for the client and although the server connects here is where I call ObjectOutputStream.

```
    ObjectOutputStream ganandorf;

    for(int i = 0; i < clients.size(); i++)
    {
       try
       {
            ganandorf = new ObjectOutputStream(clients.get(i).getOutputStream());
            ganandorf.write(1);
            ganandorf.flush();
            ganandorf.writeObject(something);
            ganandorf.flush();
       }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [getInputStream blocks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8088557/getinputstream-blocks)

Comment: I switched the location of ObjectInput and ObjectOutput and and forced ObjectOutput to flush, but it's still hanging on ObjectInput

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to use two different kinds of streams/readers/writers on the same underlying connection. You will encounter buffering issues at both ends that make it basically impossible.

I would use `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` and just write objects.

The constructor of `ObjectInputStream` blocks until it receives the header that is written by the constructor of `ObjectOutputStream`, so if you are constructing both you must construct the `ObjectOutputStream` first. You don't need to write anything and you don't need to flush it either, it does that itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only ask for 1 inputStream reference:

```
InputStream baseInputStream = sock.getInputStream();
input = new DataInputStream(baseInputStream);
zelda = new ObjectInputStream(baseInputStream);
```

same goes for outputStreams

Comment: InputStreams can only be read once, so this is not a good idea.

Comment: as long as he uses only one at once, there should be no problem.

Comment: Does OP intend to synchronize the accesses to the is (and os)? Still, it's true it looks kinky. Prima facie, of course.

Comment: Tried this and made on OutputStream, but it's still hanging on ObjectInput. Thanks for answering though!

Comment: You are mistaken. You can ask for as many as you like. Whether they will all work together is another question.

Comment: @EJP: looking at the code for `Socket`, what is actually returned is implementation dependant. However, the AbstractPlainSocketImpl always return the same InputStream, no matter how many times you ask.

Comment: @njzk2 Of course it's always the same stream. That's different from not being able to *ask* for it many *times*.

Answer (score -1):

I never found out what happened with **ObjectInputStream**, but I switched to DataInputStream and I'm currently modifying my code so it sends the piece name, x location, and y location in one string that will get broken up at the client and the board will be modified accordingly

Answer (score -1):

Open a socket on a different port and use that to create new streams.